# svcutil fails against service with a fault contract

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe, faultcontract

We have a WCF self hosted service which we have been developing for awhile.  As part of our standard we have defined a FaultContract which we apply to operations.

Recently we needed to add a new ServiceContract so we did that and added a simple method (void/no params) to it.  Once we added this contract though SVCUtil would no longer generate a proxy for us.  Instead it would error out and say that the Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost/MyService'  There is no endpoint listening blah blah blah.

We finally debugged it to the fact that the operation contract has the faultcontract.  As soon as we remove it everything works fine.  This to us is very strange because..

1) the new service contract is in the same location as all our other service contracts

2) the implementer of the service contract is the same as the implementer of all other service contracts (don't ask)

3) The FaultContract is the same as the one we use everywhere else.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this weird behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to not be FaultContracts fault.  Instead there is a problem with using the netTcp binding for mex.  After you reach a certain number of methods it just doesn't work anymore.  Solution was to switch to an http binding.